# Issue Passing the content of a custom cell using the prepareForSegue method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a custom cell which contains a label. What I want is to be able to pass the content of this label to a second view controller when the row is selected.
The code I have works fine on tables without custom cells:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    //labelDisplayLedQty is the name of the custom label
    cell.labelDisplayLedQty.text = inputLedQty.text

    return cell
}
```

Here is the code I have in the `prepareForSegue` method. As I said this code works fine if I use it with a table that doesn't contain a custom cell.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let rowIndex: NSIndexPath = tableList.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let selectedRow: UITableViewCell = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex)!
    let contentFromSelectedRow: String = selectedRow.textLabel!.text!

    if let secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DriverDetailsViewController where
       segue.identifier == "segueDriverDetails" {
        secondVC.messageContentFromMainController = contentFromSelectedRow + " This message is from main viewController"
    }
}
```

With the code above I get the following error when I select a row, which make sense since I'm not using the default textLabel:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I tried changing...

```
let contentFromSelectedRow: String = selectedRow.textLabel!.text!
```

to...

```
let contentFromSelectedRow: String = selectedRow.labelDisplayLedQty!.text!
```

But then I get the following hint error message:

```
Value of type 'UITableViewCell has no member labelDisplayLedQty'
```

Can someone tell me what do I need to do to be able to pass the content of the selected row to a second view controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said, that you are using a custom `UITableViewCell`. Therefore you have to cast the `selectedRow` to have the type of that custom cell. Try this:

```
let selectedRow = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex)! as! CustomTableViewCellName
```

This should enable you to access your custom label.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the following two lines fixed the issue:  `let selectedRow = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex)! as! CustomCell` `let contentFromSelectedRow:String = selectedRow.labelDisplayLedQty!.text!`

Comment: Exactly. It seems you've understood the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on this lines:

```
let selectedRow:UITableViewCell = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex)!
let contentFromSelectedRow:String = selectedRow.textLabel!.text!
```

`selectedRow` shouldn't be an `UITableViewCell` since you're using a custom cell

This should fix:

```
let selectedRow = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex) as! CustomCell
let contentFromSelectedRow:String = selectedRow.labelDisplayLedQty.text
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, indeed what you suggested fixed the issue

Answer (score 4):

Since your table view cell is a custom cell you have to cast the type

```
let selectedRow = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex) as! CustomCell
```

Note: Calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `prepareForSegue` is always the worst choice. The first choice is to get the data from the model (the data source array) rather than from the view (the table view cell).

Comment: First of all thank you. Hmm, sorry but I'm not sure how to fix the issue by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the prepareForSegue.

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are updating the view (e.g. a label) with `label.text = datasource[indexPath.row]`. If you need the value of the label just do the same in `prepareForSegue`: get the value from the data source.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you get the error with the `CustomCell` but not with the default cell class. Why? Lets look at your code:

```
let selectedRow: UITableViewCell = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex)!
```

This code above gets the UITableViewCell class, not the custom class. BUT. You created a CustomClass cell, not the UITableViewCell. That is why it is starting to get more and more confusing. First of all, you have to specify the class you are using. But still, using `!` is not what you want in your code, I would use `if let` or even `guard` statement.

```
guard let selectedRow = tableList.cellForRowAtIndexPath(rowIndex) as? CustomCell else {
    return
}
```

**Second**, you now get to use properties for your custom class. As you can see, you couldn't get the property `labelDisplayLedQty`, because it is not the property of UITableViewCell. **Now you can use it**. Your custom cell doesn't have the `textLabel` property, so it won't work also.

```
let contentFromSelectedRow: String = selectedRow.labelDisplayLedQty!.text
```

**Third**, I would test if you always get the indexPath, since you are again unwrapping the optional with `!`. The line below is not that safe (you can use guard or if let again):

```
let rowIndex: NSIndexPath = tableList.indexPathForSelectedRow!
```

**Last**, but not least - surely you can get the access to the data source in different way that by accessing cell - use the array that you fill your cells with.

Comment: If **all** cells are created as `CustomCell` what else could it be? The implicit unwrapped optional is absolutely safe in that case and optional binding is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Now they are (maybe not, depends on his code), but in the future it can lead to problems. You should always look into the future with your code.

Comment: No offense but that is not what Swift is designed for.

Comment: Okay, you are going deep with your thoughts, it is not needed here. But thanks for your time.